# UFT is getting killed while opening database connection

Tags: hp-uft

Running the below line result with killing UFT while executing:

```
gdb_Conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=" & & ";Uid=" & ";Pwd=" & & ";"
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you get?

I expect that there are variables between the two & & and there's missing & after the uid? So it looks like this?

```
gdb_Conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=" & server & ";Uid=" & uid & ";Pwd=" & password & ";"
```

If not you need to complete the line with the variables holding correct values (server name, user and password pair that has access to it).

Otherwise check that the server is running, you can connect to it manually, the user has access etc.